How can I send a value from a component in the layout of my .net 8.0 blazor webassembly to a page outside the webassembly?
I have created a .net 8.0 blazor web application solution.
The web project is standard with the following code:
App.razor
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-GB">
<head>
<base href="/"/>
<title>My Awesome Web Application</title>
<HeadOutlet/>
</head>
<body>
<Routes/>
<script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

Layout.razor
@using myawesomeproject.shared.components
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<Header @rendermode="InteractiveWebAssembly"/>

@Body

Myawesomehomepage.razor
@page "/"
<h1>Home page</h1>

Myawesomeotherpage.razor
@page "/myawesomeotherpage/{message}"

<h1>@(message)</h1>

@code
{
  [Parameter]
  public string? message { get; set; }
}

In a project of shared razor components, I have the following:
Header.razor
<header>
  <input @bind="message"/>
  <button @onclick="Send">Send message</button>
</header>
  
@code
{
  [Inject]
  private NavigationManager? navigation { get; set; }

  private string? message { get; set; }

  public void Send()
  {
    navigation!.NavigateTo("/myawesomeotherpage/" + message);
  }
}

he layout razor component contains the header razor component, which in turn contains a text input, bound to a local string called 'message' and a button.
Clicking the button does nothing.
How do I send the string 'message', as a parameter, to myawesomeotherpage, please?

There was more in the header, albeit not pertinent to the problem, but it was required to run client side.
This is not the solution I would like, but it works.
Layout.razor
@using myawesomeproject.shared.components
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<Header @rendermode="InteractiveWebAssembly"/>
<Message @rendermode="InteractiveServer"/>

@Body

I created a separate component for handling the messages:
Message.razor
<input @bind="message"/>
<button @onclick="Send">Send message</button>
  
@code
{
  [Inject]
  private NavigationManager? navigation { get; set; }

  private string? message { get; set; }

  public void Send()
  {
    navigation!.NavigateTo("/myawesomeotherpage/" + message);
  }
}


You can put the header Component in the client app. I put it in   ParamerDemo.shared.components  ,the browser console has some mistake like this:

I put it in  ParamerDemo.Client.shared.components like this  it works well:

The result is :


Is this the only way, XieMan?
I was hoping the LayoutService you created in my other question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78836763, might be used to add an event listener to the component.
Or something.

I've recreated the components, placed them in ervy folder, in every project and it's still not working for me.
I'm not totally sure, but some articles on github suggest it might be a bug in blazor.

You can check your pragram.cs file  this config is like this: builder.Services.AddRazorComponents().AddServerSideBlazor().AddWebAssemblyHostedBlazorWebAssembly();                                           and
           app.MapRazorComponents<App>().AddInteractiveServerRenderMode() .AddInteractiveWebAssemblyRenderMode(); You can see this tutorials learn more:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/render-modes?view=aspnetcore-8.0


This question is not similar to last question.In last question all page should get the value of the input ,so we should create a global variable.This question we use  navigation  transfer parameters just get the value in one page.

You're absolutely correct, XieMan and it was naive of me to suggest it.
I now understand the process more, but moving the component from its current project is not an option.

If a component /page rendermode = InteractiveWebAssembly/InteractiveAuto ,you should put it in the client app,the tutorial  tell us where should we put our component.

You ARE correct, XieMan and normally, I would, but my Header and Message components are shared across many different projects.
If I moved them, other projects would break.
